# Divide array into subarrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following array, I have to make sure to divide it in this way into subarray, taking into consideration the first part of the name followed by / as a criterion for subdivision, for example "name/other".

Can you give me a hand?

```swift
var a = ["origin/a", "origin/b", "origin/c", "remo/a", "remo/d", "remo/c", "next/g"]

var b = {
 origin: ["a", "b", "c"], 
 remo: ["a", "d", "c"], 
 next: ["g"]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you loooked a `componentsSeparated(by:)` ? A `map()` & a `Dictionary.groupinig(by:_:)` could do the trick. I guess `b` is a Dictionary? Or a custom `struct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could used `reduce(into:_:)` to do so:

```
let reduced = a.reduce(into: [String: [String]]()) { partialResult, currentTerm in
    let components = currentTerm.components(separatedBy: "/")
    guard components.count == 2 else { return }
    partialResult[components[0]] = partialResult[components[0], default: [String]()] + [components[1]]
}
print(reduced)
```

Output:

```
$>["remo": ["a", "d", "c"], "next": ["g"], "origin": ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Comment: A good solution, but in this case if I wanted to cycle the elements of reduced.
taking the key (orign) and then the single elements (a, b, c) to cycle them, how can I do?

Comment: RepoRemote(content: remotesNameValue, name: key)

Comment: remotesNameValue would be an object: RepoBranch (name: branch)

Comment: So `b` is not not a Dictionary? It's unclear, because for `RepoRemote` seems to allow only ONE key, while there are more (origin, next, remo). You can iterate on them: `for (aKey, values in reduced { let repoRemote = RepoRemove(content: values, name: key)}`? Your issue is unclear. or `RepoRemote(content: reduced["remote"]!, key: "remote")`?

Comment: ```let ccc: [RepoRemote] = (reduced.map { (key, array) in
                let content: [RepoBranch] = array.map { RepoBranch(name: $0) }
                return RepoRemote(content: content, name: key)
            })```

Comment: Do you think it is right written?

Comment: Seems fine if it works, and you understand what you've done (for possible fixes/modifications in future, you should be able to do them).

Answer (score 1):

One idea is like this:

First we need to separate the keys for the dictionary and all the values that need to be gathered together:

```
let keysValues = a
    .map { $0.components(separatedBy: "/") }
    .compactMap { components -> (String, String)? in

    guard components.count == 2 else { return nil }
    return (components.first!, components.last!)
}
```

Now we need to reduce that into a dictionary of `[String: [String]]` by grouping together the values for each key:

```
var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]
let answer = keysValues.reduce(into: dict) { (d, kv) in
    let (k, v) = kv
    d[k, default: []] += [v]
}
```